# Cannot login to wordpress admin once i change the admin url

Tags: wordpress

I have just installed a wordpress website, and i was working with some security measures but now my wordpress admin is not loading. It gets redirected to page not found.

Steps which i have done

1. I have installed wordpress in the following url icg.projects.com
2. Then i have moved the wp files to a sub-folder named "core-files" (as per this url http://www.ampercent.com/move-core-wordpress-files-custom-directory/6211/).

Till now frontend and wp admin works fine

1. Now i just tried to change the admin url to icgadmin (ie. from icg.projects.com/core-files/wp-admin/ to icg.projects.com/core-files/icgadmin/). The problem is after giving the username and password in wp-login page my url becomes http://icg.projects.com/core-files/icgadmin/. But the content of the page is "Page not Found". But the actually i should get the wordpress admin.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance